Adding an SSD to Ubuntu laptop
I have a dual boot laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 11. I have a spare SSD at home and I would like to add that extra storage to my linux partition. How should I proceed? Is it enough to insert it in the laptop or, if not, how am I supposed to proceed? Thank you in advance!

You didn't say how you would be attaching the new SSD (USB3, caddy replacing a DVD, m.2 replacing a wireless card,...) so we cannot give very specific advice. Partitions need not be changed if you just add new storage to a mount point like /usr/local/data.

That's true! I added it via m.2 port! I followed the link suggested by graham and it worked smoothly!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
